# Why are outbound SSH connections from Google CloudRun to EC2 instances unspeakably slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, google-cloud-run

I have a Node API deployed to Google CloudRun and it is responsible for managing external servers (clean, new Amazon EC2 Linux VM's), including through SSH and SFTP. SSH and SFTP actually work eventually but the connections take **2-5 MINUTES** to initiate. Sometimes they timeout with handshake timeout errors.

The same service running on my laptop, connecting to the same external servers, has no issues and the connections are as fast as any normal SSH connection.

The deployment on CloudRun is pretty standard. I'm running it with a service account that permits access to secrets, etc. Plenty of memory allocated.

I have a VPC Connector set up, and have routed all traffic through the VPC connector, as per the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip

I also tried setting `UseDNS no` in the */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file on the EC2 as per some suggestions online re: slow SSH logins, but that has not make a difference.

I have rebuilt and redeployed the project a few dozen times and all tests are on brand new EC2 instances.

I am attempting these connections using open source wrappers on the Node *ssh2* library, *node-ssh* and *ssh2-sftp-client*.

Ideas?

Comment: does the same happen if you run Cloud Run locally via minikube?

Comment: You proably don't have an active request during this on Cloud Run, as outside of the active request the CPU is throttled. Best for this pipeline is Cloud Workflows.

Comment: Latency issues usually require to examine the logs and metrics of the affected service which is something we cannot do here. I would suggest opening a support ticket.

Comment: That's really interesting @Pentium10. Looking at the notes I'd managed to miss about how CloudRun throttles between requests, I think that's probably it, because these are jobs that I'm starting responsive to polling a redis message queue. Even the polling process is a questionable fit for CloudRun. That's easy to rework. I'll post a note here if that works.

Comment: @Pentium10 - that was exactly it. Rejiggering the workflow so the API sitting on CloudRun is only triggered through endpoint calls resolves the issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run works only until you have a HTTP request active.

You proably don't have an active request during this on Cloud Run, as outside of the active request the CPU is throttled.

Best for this pipeline is Cloud Workflows and regular Compute Engine instances.

You can setup a Workflow to start a Compute Engine for this task, and stop once it finished doing the steps.

I am the author of article: [Run shell commands and orchestrate Compute Engine VMs with Cloud Workflows](https://medium.com/p/e345e616a24) it will guide you how to setup.

Executing the Workflow can be triggered by Cloud Scheduler or by HTTP ping.